# React and DRF on Different subdomains

Tags: reactjs, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out why I am getting 405(NOT ALLOWED) on all pages. I assume that somewhere I missed something but I cannot figure out what exactly. Both of them are via NGINX.

NOTE: I would like to mention that backend was tested via postman and is working well.

Comment: did you check browser console? sometimes there are non-obvious errors, maybe cors

Comment: yes I have checked now i understood  that problems is between pm2 and express js